# How do I have a class hold an array of itself by using STL containers/smart pointers?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, stl, std

So I essentially want to do this:

```
struct A {

    A *children[10];
};
```

However, when I do this and create a destructor such as:

```
 virtual ~A() {
        for (A *child: children) {
            delete child;
        }
    }
```

I get a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. So how can I accomplish holding a list of A within A using an STL class so I don't have to worry about new/delete? I tried vector and get an "incomplete type" error.

Comment: Did you try `std::vector<A*>`? I don't suppose `A` ever contains itself? I'm just guessing here cause there isn't enough information here to do anything with. Consider [edit]ing your question to contain a [mcve], which for your example should be no longer than about 20 lines.

Comment: In `C++17` you are able to write `struct A { std::vector<A> children; }`; without these worries of incomplete types. This might not be helpful immediately but if your system permits, an upgrade to the newest standard would help out :)

Comment: In the code shown here the pointers have not been initialized, so each of those deletes produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Your first cycle iterates "by value". It does not change `a.get()->children` array, contrary to what you apparently believe.

Comment: Rolling back, you can't just ask a new question in place of the old one after you have been given the answer. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
for (shared_ptr<A> child: a.get()->children) {
```

does not iterate over `children` -- it iterates over *copies* of the pointers in `children`.  So in each iteration, you make a copy of the (null) shared pointer (`child`) then set that loop-local copy to a newly allocated object, then `child` goes out of scope and the allocated object is freed.  The pointers in the `children` array are never modified.

What you want is:

```
for (shared_ptr<A> &child: a.get()->children) {
```

the explicit reference (`&`) means that in each iteration of the loop, `child` will be a reference to the `shared_ptr` in the `children` array rather than a copy.  So when you assign to it, it will modify the array.

Comment: So the questions was completely changed, your answer suits the new question, mine suits the old. What should i do here, roll back the changing edit? Give up?

Answer (score 3):

So

1. In `for (A *child: A) { delete child; ...` you should probably be iterating over `children`, not `A`.
2. For the above to work, you should store your children in a `std::vector`, not a raw array (`std::vector<A> children`).
3. Use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) of your choice (like `std::shared_ptr`) instead of raw pointers, then you don't have to delete anything.

Comment: Thanks I figured out how to use stl containers, however am running into an initialization problem, see updated question

Comment: @BeardMagician Do not change the question to something completely different. Ask a new question instead.